# Find String in csv with batch

Tags: string, batch-file, cmd, find

I have a CSV file below.

**abc.csv :**

```
ABC-1000-DDDD
DEF-5656-RRRR
GHI-3313-YYTYT
XYZ-653-DFFFD



Total 6434 Record : 65 Page : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 Next>>
```

I want to save the 65 number to text file. The 65 number is the total number of pages. The 65 number is not fix. sometime 5 or 20 or 30, etc.

**my batch script is :**

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /L "Record:" abc.csv') do echo %%a> page.txt
```

Where mistake my script? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findstr` outputs the entire line which you can see if you run `findstr /L "Record :" abc.csv` in the command prompt console.

Use `for /f "tokens=5" %%a in ('findstr /L "Record :" abc.csv') do echo %%a> page.txt`

N.B. there's a space before `:` in the text you've posted!